# Summing Data on Two Rows with a Similar Identifier

Tags: sql, sum, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm attempting to sum a column 'Quantity' in our database whenever an Item ID is either itself or if its itself with a zero in front (whether the ID is 2447 or 02447 as an example in this case):

I started with the following to get the sums of the IDs:

```
SELECT
"TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_ScanCode" As LineItemID,
"TJ_StockInventory"."INV_ScanCode" As InventoryID,
"TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_ReceiptAlias" As ReceiptAlias,
"TJ_StockInventory"."INV_Name" As ItemName,
"TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_LIT_FK" As LineDiscount,
SUM("TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_Quantity") AS Quantity

FROM "TJ_StockInventory" LEFT OUTER JOIN "TJ_TransactionJournalDetail" ON "TJ_StockInventory"."INV_PK" = "TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."INV_PK"
WHERE ecrs.TJ_TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_StartTime > '2020-01-17 00:00:00.000'

AND ecrs.TJ_TransactionJournalDetail.TLI_EndTime < '2020-01-19 23:59:59.999'
AND INV_DPT_FK = 49
AND "TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_LIT_FK" = 1
GROUP BY LineItemID,InventoryID,ReceiptAlias,ItemName,LineDiscount
ORDER BY InventoryID;
```

These are the results the quantity of which I'm attempting to combine:

```
LineItemID,InventoryID,ReceiptAlias,ItemName,LineDiscount,Quantity
    '2447','02447         ','DELI-BEAR CLAW EA','Bear Claw',1,1.0000
    '02447','02447         ','DELI-BEAR CLAW EA','Bear Claw',1,30.0000
```

What I'm looking for:

```
'2447','02447         ','DELI-BEAR CLAW EA','Bear Claw',1,31.0000
```

-or-

```
'02447','02447         ','DELI-BEAR CLAW EA','Bear Claw',1,31.0000
```

as long as the quantity is 31.

I basically want to combine the quantity of two rows if  the LineItemID is the same as "0" concatenated with the LineItemID on another line.  Or another way of possibly accomplishing it would be to combine all items with the same InventoryID, but that is in the StockInventory table, not the TransactionJournal table which has the quantity that I'm summing.

And have tried a number of solutions, first I tried a CASE statement but couldn't figure out how to apply it across rows:

```
....
SUM (
    CASE WHEN ( "TJ_StockInventory"."INV_ScanCode" = STRING('0',"TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_ScanCode",'         ') )
        THEN "TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_Quantity"
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Quantity
FROM "TJ_StockInventory" LEFT OUTER JOIN     
....
```

I also tried partitioning by ItemID to combine the quantity when the InventoryIDs were the same:

```
....
SUM("TJ_TransactionJournalDetail"."TLI_Quantity") over (partition by "TJ_StockInventory"."INV_ScanCode") AS Quantity
....
```

But neither of these solutions worked.  I chose to "else 0" the case statement just to narrow it down to that one item, but in all cases it kept the lines separate and did not combine the quantities.

I've looked at a number of tutorials but none seem to deal with this specific case, and I haven't found anything that was hinting at a solution for this.  That being said, I have difficulty wrapping my mind around database programming at times and am open to the idea that I may be approaching this in the incorrect way.

A couple of pseudocode examples of what I'm looking for

```
if LineItemID of this row = CONCAT('0', LineItemID) of another row
then sum the quantities of those rows
```

-or-

```
if InventoryID of this row and InventoryID of another row are equal
then sum them even if the LineItemIDs are different
```

Any help, pointers or directions to examples or docs online that could help with this would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: SQLAnywhere 17, sorry I must have tagged another by accident.  Editing it now.

Comment: you already know the `InventoryID` is the same so group by `InventoryID,ReceiptAlias,ItemName,LineDiscount`; it's not clear (to me) what the expected output is (ie, what would you expect those 2 lines to look like when combined?)

Comment: Hi markp, thanks for the suggestion!  I grouped as you suggested but it still did not provide the desired output.  What I'm looking for is that those two bear claw lines are combined into one line with a count of '31' instead of two lines, one with a count of '30' and the other with the count of '1'.  When I grouped according to your criteria there were still two separate lines with two separate counts.

Comment: please update the question with the desired output; it's not clear from your comment what you expect to see as `LineItemID`; and fwiw, most people aren't going to scour the comments looking for addendums/details to the question

Comment: I updated it, markp, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to remove "LineItemID" from the aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(tjd."TLI_ScanCode") As LineItemID,
       si."INV_ScanCode" As InventoryID,
       tjd."TLI_ReceiptAlias" As ReceiptAlias,
       si."INV_Name" As ItemName,
       tjd."TLI_LIT_FK" As LineDiscount,
       SUM(tjd."TLI_Quantity") AS Quantity
FROM "TJ_StockInventory" si LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     "TJ_TransactionJournalDetail" tjd
     ON si."INV_PK" = tjd."INV_PK"
WHERE tjd.TLI_StartTime > '2020-01-17' AND
      tjd.TLI_EndTime < '2020-01-20' AND
      INV_DPT_FK = 49 AND 
      tjd."TLI_LIT_FK" = 1
GROUP BY InventoryID, ReceiptAlias, ItemName, LineDiscount
ORDER BY InventoryID;
```

Comment: Nice!  Thank you, Gordon!  One thing in case anyone else looks at this, tjd."INV_Name" should be si."INV_Name".  Gordon, how does "MAX" remove it from the aggregate?  It makes sense because earlier when I tried removing it from the group by clause I got an error telling me it needed to be included.  I adjusted an earlier statement I made and just added the MAX and removed the LineItemID from the group by statement and it worked as well.  What does selecting the maximum value in a column do to allow me to remove it from the aggregate?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user4333011 . . . Any column that is NOT the argument to an aggregation function needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.  Generally, columns that are in the `GROUP BY` are not also arguments to aggregation functions.

Comment: I see, so you used MAX as an aggregate function processing TLI_ScanCode to make it possible to exclude it from the GROUP BY statement.  Great thinking and information, thanks Gordon!

Comment: Also, thanks for tidying it up a bit, your more compact style definitely beats my verbose literal style and I hope to integrate it more as I move forward.